# selenium - webdriver won't go back to previous page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to click on a link, scrape data from that webpage, go back again, click on the next link and so on. But, I am not able to go back to the previous page for some reason. I observed that I can execute the code to go back if I am outside the loop, and I can't figure out what is wrong with the loop. I tried to use driver.back() too and yet it won't work. Any help is appreciated!! TYI

```
x = 0 #counter
contents=[]
for link in soup_level1.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r"^/new-homes/arizona/phoenix/"), tabindex=-1):

    python_button =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='clearfix len-results-items len-view-list']//a[contains(@href,'/new-homes/arizona/phoenix/')]")

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",python_button)

    driver.implicitly_wait(50)

    soup_level2=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    a=soup_level2.find('ul',  class_ ='plan-info-lst')

    for names in a.find('li'):
         contents.append(names.span.next_sibling.strip())


    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

    driver.implicitly_wait(50)

    x += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Some more information about your usecase interms of:

- Selenium client version
- WebDriver variant and version
- Browser type and version

would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way.

---

However to go back to the previous page you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using [`back()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver): Goes one step backward in the browser history.

  - Usage:

    ```
    driver.back()
    ```
- Using [`execute_script()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script): Synchronously Executes [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) in the current window/frame.

  - Usage:

    ```
    driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
    ```

---

### Usecase Internet Explorer

As per @james.h.evans.jr's comment in the discussion [driver.navigate().back() blocks when back button triggers a javascript alert on the page](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2181#issuecomment-191939439) if you are using [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) at times `back()` may not work and is pretty much expected as [ie](/questions/tagged/ie) navigates back in the history by using the *COM GoBack()* method of the *IWebBrowser* interface. Given that, if there are any modal dialogs that appear during the execution of the method, the method will block.

You may even face similar issues while invoking `forward()` in the history, and submitting forms. The *GoBack* method can be executed on a separate thread which would involve calling a few not-very-intuitive COM object marshaling functions e.g. `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream()` and `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()` but there seems we can't do much about that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 
`driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")`

You can try using

**driver.back()** see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#navigation-history-and-location)

Please be aware that this functionality depends entirely on the underlying driver. It’s just possible that something unexpected may happen when you call these methods if you’re used to the behavior of one browser over another.

Comment: I tried driver.back() too but still it won't work @Azy_Crw4282

Comment: My guess is that since its looping through, its unable to go back to the previous page as elements are constantly changing. This also explains why it works outside the loop. What happens when you set implicit wait above the `driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")`. Try and increase the wait time also